# zsh - iterate over files matched using parameter in the script

Tags: zsh

I have this code executed fine and correctly in the zsh shell:

```
for f in ./A*.html; do; echo $f; done
```

output

```
./Aliasing.html
./Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands.html
./Alternative-Completion.html
./Arguments.html
./Arithmetic-Evaluation.html
./Arithmetic-Expansion.html
./Array-Parameters.html
./Author.html
./Availability.html
```

However when I use this code, but sending a matching string (./A*.html) as a parameter in the zsh function, it will display only the first file

script:

```
displayy() {
for f in $1; do; echo $f; done
}
```

command:

```
%displayy ./A*.html
```

output

```
./Aliasing.html
```

I would rather expect the same files are printed out as when executing for loop in shell (first example). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Grazie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `displayy ./A*.html` command is that `*` is expanded by zsh **before** it is passed to the `dispayy` function. So in fact your command looks like this:

```
$ displayy ./Aliasing.html ./Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands.html  ...
```

Then in `displayy` you print just first argument: `./Aliasing.html`.

The easiest way to solve this issue is to change one char (`1`=>`@`) in you `displayy` definition:

```
displayy() {
for f in "$@"; do; echo "$f"; done
}
```

This way iteration of loop goes through all `display` arguments. Additionally I recommend to put double quotes around variables as a good habit, even if in this example there are no whitespaces in file names.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info. It helped, now the script works. I appreciate this. Have a nice day, sir. :)

Comment: Note that in `zsh`, `$@` and `"$@"` are identical under the default settings.